# Display Images in Scroll view

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml

I am new to android programming. I'm currently developing an app for my project using mysql DB.
I have an activity That will display a lot of information about an Event or place
this activity long so I use Scroll view.

**The problem is :**
I want to display an images with a Caption "I don't know the number it depend on how much image in database so each time I add a new Image in DB it will appear in this activity "

I was thinking to use GridView but the problem is I'm already make the layout scrollable. so What can I use to display the images?

Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:background="#eaedf1">


<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_event_image"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#efcc08"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/Null"/>

<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/MyRating"
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_event_image"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="0.1" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_write"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_event_name"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_event_name"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#eaedf1"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
android:drawableRight="@drawable/comment_small"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_fav"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_event_name"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_event_name"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
android:background="#eaedf1"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/fav_small"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_event_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/MyRating"
android:layout_below="@+id/MyRating"
android:text="@string/Event_name"
android:textColor="#505152"
android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View android:id="@+id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />

<!-- Second Row -->

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_rate_place"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:text="@string/Descrption" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_event_description"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
/>

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />

<!-- Third Row -->

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_End_date_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_End_date"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/End_date"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_Start_date_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_Start_date"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:text="@string/Start_date"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />



</LinearLayout>


<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />


<!-- Fourth Row -->   

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_pictures"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:text="@string/pictures" />

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gv_pictures"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="205dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

</GridView>

<!-- Fifth Row -->        

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_contact"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:text="@string/contact" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_contact_info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
/>

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />    


<!-- Sixth Row -->

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center|left"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_person"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/Null"
android:src="@drawable/person" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_avrage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="50dp" />

<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/Money_rating"
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="0.1"
/>

</LinearLayout>        

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />


<!-- Seventh Row -->



<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:text="@string/location" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_location_info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
/>

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />

<!-- 8 Row -->



<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_comment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:text="@string/comments" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_comment_info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Null"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
/>     

<View android:id="@id/primerdivisor"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#505152" />


</LinearLayout>   

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why are you storing images in the database ? Store it inside the `drawable` folder which can be found inside `res` folder.

Comment: Kindly note that this is not a good design at all, you need to implement this with a list or grid view. Also, store your image with in a folder instead of DB.

Comment: Use a ListView or GridView if you are taking images from an online database use PARSE to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GirdView is scrollable on it's own, you can use it. But I suggest the new RecylerView and using GridLayoutManager on it. It is scrollable on it's own too, but is more efficient than GridView and a whole lot more customizable and the most important thing... You can find tons of good examples for it.

Also tako a look at this Google's example how to load Bitmaps efficiently: http://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/index.html